# Out-of-band programmatic identification of Windows Server vs Client

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-server, computer-forensics

I have some free-standing C++ code (i.e. not a Windows program) that needs to identify the version of Windows that is installed on a PC.

I can easily differentiate between the different Windows client releases by kernel version (e.g. `GetFileVersionInfo` on ntoskrnl.exe), however I'm wondering if there's a reliable way to distinguish between a client and server installation.

A problem arises when using this method to distinguish between Windows Vista SP2 and Windows Server 2008 SP2 (6.0 build 6002 the both of them) and Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 (6.1 build 7600 for RTM and 6.1 build 7601 for SP2, both). What is a reliable (and preferably as straight forward as possible, avoiding the registry would be great as access to Win32 API is not available) method of identifying client vs server OSes correctly for code running outside the environment?

I suppose I could check for files only present on the server edition (what's a good file guaranteed to be on any server edition install, regardless of configuration?), check the Panther folder (which is safe to delete, so no guarantees there), etc. but I'm sure this is a problem that people have run into before and (hopefully) solved more elegantly?

(Sidenote: this question has been asked [on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368370/how-to-distinguish-the-server-version-from-the-client-version-of-windows), but the solution (WMI) is inapplicable for out-of-band checking)

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why do you need to do this?  I've been pondering for hours and can't think of a use case ...

Comment: It's to lock or unlock certain features of recovery software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up searching for a number of binaries in the system32 directory that are generally associated with the Server Edition of Windows. It's not very clean, but in practice it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean about out of band checking, so I'm going to ignore that for the moment.

The normal way would be to call [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451.aspx), and look at the `wProductType` member of the [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx).

Comment: I did indicate in my post that "out-of-band" means that I'm not *in* Windows and I don't have access to the Windows API. Will look into `wProductType` and see if I can grab it from the PE headers in `ntoskrnl.exe`

Comment: Do you know where `GetVersionEx` gets `OSVERSIONINFOEX`? I cannot locate any of that in the PE object headers for ntoskrnl.exe: http://pastebin.com/DTADp2EV

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I'm pretty sure it retrieves data from the registry. There is (or at one time was) a hack to let workstation act more like server (allow more client connections and such) by modifying the registry to it thought it was a copy of server; the binary files themselves at least used to be the same. Don't know if that's true any more though (it became prominent around the NT4/Win2K time frame).

Comment: If that's what it boils down to, I could manually load and search the registry hive, but I'd much rather not...

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I sure can't blame you there, but I'm not sure how much else you can really depend on either.

Answer (score 0):

A PE image does NOT specify whether the image should work on a client or server. It only specifies the runtime requirements regarding subsystem, dependencies, memory, affinity, etc...

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an answer to my question.. did you mean to post this as a comment?

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is a comment. :-)

Comment: FYI you can delete and repost it as a comment by clicking the link under your answer. And, btw, the PE header does contain subsystem info, and dependency info can be pulled from the binary. You can see the subsystem info in this link: http://pastebin.com/DTADp2EV

Comment: My apologies, I misread your post. In that case, the PE image *does* provide version info, which I had originally be banking on to solve my problem, but cannot for the reasons outlined in my post.

Comment: No problem! :-) The version info provided by PE is only the version of the required OS to run the image but not the type (client vs. server).